# Не выполняется исполняемый файл собранный В CODE BLOCKS

Tags: c, cgi

Программа работает когда ее запускаешь в CODE BLOCKS (язык С). При сборке же появляются два файла один .EXE, другой .о. И при открытии .EXE Выдает такую ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально, я хотел написать .cgi скрипт для своего сервера - тренеруюсь по учебнику и там были примеры на языке C и я решил попробовать написать нечто подобное, но тут даже исполняемый файл не хочет запускаться...

Comment: перейдите в настройки, на вкладку link (или linker) и добавьте `-static` к опциям линковки. Либо просто скопируйте не хватающих dll.

Comment: Добавлю, в __c::b__ надо ещё установить флаг `static link gcc library`, флаги доступны в `Опции сборки проекта` -> `Копилятор`, достаточно отметить чекбокс, не обязательно писать в формате параметра.

Comment: Я поставил флаги, но ничего не изменилось